# How do I make text have no space in between them vertically?

Tags: html, css

I want to make these 2 text boxes have no space in between them

[image: The way the website looks]

I tried using a container with the code display:flex; in it but that made the text uncentered.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h2 {
  color: navy;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">The Mains Are</h1>
<h2>BACK!</h2>
```

Comment: Start by removing all margins and padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by giving the `h2` element a `margin:0`. If you want to close the gap a little more, you can get it as close as you want by giving a **negative** `margin-top` value.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h2 {
  color: navy;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
  margin-top:-72px; /*you can change the gap by changing this value*/
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">The Mains Are</h1>
<h2>BACK!</h2>
```

Comment: This solution isn't really perfect since it still leaves a tiny bit of space

Comment: I updated it to be **perfect** for you :)

Answer (score 1):

First you can remove the margin and padding of h1 and h2, but if it's not close enough you can wrap those two titles in a div and set the line-height to whatever you want

```html
    <div class="slim">
      <h1 style="text-align:center">The Mains Are</h1>
      <h2>BACK!</h2>
    </div>
```

```css
.slim {
  line-height: 90px;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
h2 {
  color: navy;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use flexBox

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.main{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width:100vw;
  height:600px;
}
h2 {
  color: navy;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<h1>The Mains Are</h1>
<h2>BACK!</h2>
</div>
```